# Install multiple version of Python packages like node does it

Tags: python, node.js

How could I make Python support dependencies in a similar way how node does them. So that if my app depends on two packages, A and B, but they depend on different versions of package C, both version of C would be installed, one for A and one for B. So in some way, that all dependencies would be installed relatively. Really, like node_modules for node.

To be clear. I want that in my app I can do `import packageA` and `import packageB`, where `packageA` depends on `packageC==1.0` and `packageB` depends on `packageC==2.0`.

Comment: you can use virtualenv

Answer (score 2):

Yes, virtualenv is a good idea to work on the different environment for your different python project.

I am also working in the same way with a different version using virtualenv.

to do that first of all install virtualenv using pip,

```
pip install virtualenv
```

before you run "pip install -r requirements/development.txt", run this

```
virtualenv venv

source venv/bin/activate
```

inside your project directory.

but it should be outside of source code directory
because venv should not be tracked with git.

Then you can install your requirement module for project like,

```
pip install -r requirements/development.txt
```

I think this is the best method to work on the different project.

Hope this guide will help you.

Comment: This does not answer my question how could I have multiple versions of the same dependency available to the same app. Virtualenv allows me to have multiple versions of same dependency available to multiple apps.